# VS 2015 Crashes When open *.axml files using Android Designer Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I create a project using Xamarin with VS2015, and everything was great.
I did update for both VS and Xamarin then when I open any *.axml layout file VS freezing then crashing.

I try many ways to solve this , repair VS , repair Xamarin , Update Android SDK , recreate the project them add the files again , disable Xaml designer and reset the settings of VS .

the problem sometimes goes , sometimes appears and now I am stuck with the solutions , please help.

Answer (score 1):

I Solve this issue by:

1- deleting all the android virtual machines 
2- not to put theme for the toolbar if the layout contains one and make theme global for all layouts.
3- install Xamarin components from nuget source.
4- do not install Android 6.0 N Preview.
5- Java jdk 1.7.0_71 is the most stable JDK with xamarin until now , so don't update java JDK.

*some addition steps and recommendations :*

6- make all your resources names are small case.
7- not to add '-' in any resource name.
lastly .. 
Keep your Android SDK updated.

Comment: here is a detailed description :
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1114600/VS-Crashes-When-open-axml-files-using-Android-Desi

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/72005/vs-2015-crashes-when-open-axml-files-using-android-designer-xamarin/p1?new=1